# como obtengo los option del select input-field de materialize que han sido seleccionados con jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, materialize

necesito agarra los option de ese select de materialize que son prácticamente unos checkbox para poder agregarlos a un collapsible para que se visualicen, pero necesito saber como obtener esos "options seleccionados" con jquery o si es con javascript no hay problema tampoco

```html
<div class="input-field col s5 editable" >
    <select multiple>
    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
    <option value="1">codo</option>
    <option value="2">hombros</option>
    <option value="3">rodillas</option>
    <option value="4">pies</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que dices puede intuir que estas usando un `select:option` de `materialize` con la opción `multiple`, es decir te deja elegir mas de uno, para lo que pides puedes intentar esto:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  $("#prueba").formSelect();
  
  $("#obtener").on("click", () => {
    
    let instancia = M.FormSelect.getInstance($("#prueba"));
    let valores = instancia.getSelectedValues(); 
    console.log(valores);
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <div class="input-field col s5" >
        <select id="prueba" multiple>
           <option value="" disabled selected></option>
           <option value="1">codo</option>
           <option value="2">hombros</option>
           <option value="3">rodillas</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button id="obtener">Obtener checkeados</button>
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelectedValue' of undefined  me sale ese error, toma instancia como un undefined

Comment: OK trata de colocarlo asi M.FormSelect.getInstance($("#prueba")[0]); y me dices

Comment: aun continua el mismo error

Comment: le colocastes el id prueba? ve como arme el select:option

Comment: si, le puse ese id

Comment: Listo modifique mi respuesta e hice un ejemplo funcional para que te guies

Comment: Listo acabo de editar mi respuesta, pruebala y me dices

Answer (score 0):

Puede que esto te sirva

```
<div class="input-field col s5 editable" >
    <select multiple id="sel">
       <option value="" disabled selected></option>
       <option value="1">codo</option>
       <option value="2">hombros</option>
       <option value="3">rodillas</option>
       <option value="4">pies</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
    var val = $("#sel").val();
</script>
```

Comment: cuando aplico esto, selecciono unos y veo el array, el array sigue vació

Comment: claro, te guarda todos los valores seleccionados en un array, utiliza un var_dump para listarlos

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla y con Jquery (Que es lo que pones en primer lugar y supongo lo que requieres cómo ideal) sería darle un ID a tu select

HTML

```
<div class="input-field col s5 editable" >
    <select id="seleccionable" multiple>
       <option value="" disabled selected></option>
       <option value="1">codo</option>
       <option value="2">hombros</option>
       <option value="3">rodillas</option>
       <option value="4">pies</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$("#seleccionable").val() //esto regresa un array
```

Ese `array` que puedes iterar con forEach para ponerlo en el `collapsible`

JQuery

```
var select =  $("#seleccionable").val() ;

select.forEach( element => {

$("#collapsible").append(element);

})
```

Comment: cuando aplico esto, selecciono unos y veo el array, el array sigue vació